# Difference between unless () return ... ,and return ... unless()

Tags: perl

In Perl, is there any meaningful difference between:

```
return $result unless ($exist_condition);
```

and

```
unless ($exist_condition) return $result;
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The second is a syntax error. I presume you meant

```
# unless statement modifier
return $result unless $exist_condition;
```

and

```
# unless statement
unless ($exist_condition) { return $result; }
```

They're virtually the same. One difference is that the `unless` statement creates a scope (two actually), while the `unless` statement modifier does not.

```
>perl -E"my $x = 'abc'; unless (my $x = 'xyz') { return; } say $x;"
abc

>perl -E"my $x = 'abc'; return unless my $x = 'xyz'; say $x;"
xyz
```

In practice, that will probably never come up, so the difference is merely a question of style.

Answer (score 1):

As currently written, the second one is a syntax error.

If changed to:

```
unless ($exist_condition) { return $result; }
```

then there is no difference whatsoever. Use whichever one makes the most sense in context.